# How can I send a POST request to receive data from a Url?

Tags: javascript, html, post, request, fetch

I need to send a POST fetch request using pure javascript to a Url. I need to add an object to my code that looks like this: `var data = {task: ”getall"}` but I don't know where or how to include it or how to start. I'm still very new to Js and I'd like to get some help with this task.

This is my html code for the table:

```
<div>
      <input id="postall" type="button" value="POST Users" />
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>House Number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="userTablePost"></tbody>
      </table>
```

And this is my js code for displaying the data:

```
function renderUsers(users) {
    const tbody = document.getElementById("userTablePost");
    users.forEach(user => {
        let row = tbody.insertRow();
        let cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.textContent = user.id;
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.textContent = user.name;
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.textContent = user.street;
        cell = row.insertCell();
        cell.textContent = user.house_number;
    });
}
```

In theory I should receive data which can be seen in developer tools network option and than I should display that data on a Html page in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//Promise way
const postData = {task: "getall"};

fetch('https://api.github.com/gists', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(postData)
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log('Response:', data);
});


//Async await
async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/gists', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(postData)
  });

  const json = await response.json();

  console.log(json)
}

fetchData();
```

Comment: I am not sure, this answer might help him, if he doesn't know what is a POST request to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to learn about creating something called "AJAX request". The 1st googled tutorial goes to this link: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp which is not bad introduction, but I guess you will need to read a lot more.

Essentially, keywords you need to read about: XMLHttpRequest and AJAX to get your head around the concept. Then the next step, is to be aware of new API called "Fetch API" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

If you're very new to JS, this may be your first time you will use something called "asynchronous API's". The idea is you DON'T "call a function" and "get the result" in "one go" with this. What you do instead is:

1. You issue a REQUEST to do something (fetch data from server) - you do it by creating XMLHttpRequest() object (read tutorials).
2. You tell your REQUEST object "hey, when you finish, call my function gotData()"
3. Then your code finishes or does something else, like shows progress indicator or "please wait" thing.
4. Some time later when the browser GETs/POSTs/does other magic, and have fetched the data for you, it will call your "gotData()" function.

...if it looks hard at the beginning - don't give up, it's really a very important programming pattern to understand as you will see more and more of that later.

Hope that helps!